# Wordpress Contact form 7: display a dropdown menu after a checkbox select

Tags: css, wordpress, checkbox, contact-form

i'm working on a website http://yr-neu.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/professionals/ and as you can see here i'm using a contact form on the right with a dropdown menu.

What i need is to display another dropdown menu depending of what you choose in the first dropdown menu.

Is this possible?

Comment: You need to use ajax call for that.

Answer (score 0):

Similiar I have done in here: [click here](http://carpark.lt/category/lengvieji-automobiliai/) you can view via source code. Made with jquery